# UISplitViewController with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm a beginner in the iOS world.
I would like to have an app that is based on UISplitViewController, however on some cases a button on the detail view (which is UINavigationController) will open a UI on the entire screen (with back button which will take back to splitViewController).
Does the only option (legitimate from apple), is modeling it with ModalView?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure off the top of my head whether it's 'HIG-friendly', but you could implement something whereby when the user clicks the button, you send a message back to your AppDelegate and tell it to swap your splitViewController with your fullScreenViewController at the window level.

For example, in your `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)showFullScreenController
{
    if (self.splitViewController.superview != nil) {    // Just check that the split view controller is currently showing
        FullScreenViewController *newFullScreenController = [[FullScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FullScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.fullScreenController = newFullScreenController;
        [newFullScreenController release];

        [self.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];    // "YES" assumes you are animating the transition
        [self.fullScreenController viewWillAppear:YES];

        // Remove old view and add new one.
        [self.splitViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [window addSubview:self.fullScreenController.view];

        [self.splitViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
        [self.fullScreenController viewDidAppear:YES];

        self.splitViewController = nil;
    }
}
```

This method can easily be turned into a 'view switching' method by utilising the corresponding `else` statement and loading the `splitViewController` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have one concerns: I would like to go back to the splitview from the fullscreencon. (i think that you release it)

Comment: @adi biton: In the example above, I did release the splitViewController. You can either recreate it when you need to go back from the fullScreenView (the code would look very similar to the example above), or you could not release the reference to the controller in the first place. The latter is not recommended, as otherwise you are unnecessarily holding onto a controller that is not in use (waste of memory).